# WebSocketException on SignalR server when HubConnection.Stop() is called from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr.client

I am creating a web app using ASP.Net that is utilizing SignalR for client communication.

Whenever my client side code attempts to Close a `HubConnection` instance, using either the `.Stop()` method or wrapping the `HubConnection` in a using block, the server starts throwing `System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketsException`s.

My server is being hosted by Visual Studio using IIS Express, and I have tried client code in both Linqpad and as a stand-alone exe. Both clients produced the same server exceptions.

My client side code (with unnecessary details removed) looks like this

```
async Task Main()
{
    var signalServerLocation = "http://localhost:5462/signalr";

    using (var hubConnection = new HubConnection(signalServerLocation))
    {
        await hubConnection.Start();
    }
}
```

The exception that gets raised looks like this

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException occurred
  HResult=0x800703E3
  Message=The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
  Source=System.Web
```

with a stack trace of

```
at System.Web.WebSockets.WebSocketPipe.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ReadFragmentAsync>b__0(Int32 hrError, Int32 cbIO, Boolean fUtf8Encoded, Boolean fFinalFragment, Boolean fClose)
```

This exception is non-fatal so it doesn't crash my server, but continuing through it leads to more exceptions of the same type being thrown, as well as `System.OperationCancelledException`s with the description of `The operation was cancelled`.

I've searched around a bit but couldn't find a straight answer as to why this happens.

So my question is this. Is there something I can do to stop these Exceptions from being thrown, or are they expected? Is there a problem with the way I am connecting?

Comment: Why are you using 'using' ? You should dispose the hubConnection when the program exits... i.e. on service stop etc...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?